# Update table Data without using while loop in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, select

in sql i have table data like below

```
id      type     amount       
1      type1       2000    
2      type1       1000     
3      type2        500    
4      type3       3000    
5      type1       2000   
6      type2        500        
7      type3       5000    
8      type1       1000
```

and i want to get datas in select statement like below

```
id      type     amount      current   
1      type1       2000         2000                
2      type1       1000         1000                 
3      type2        500          500                 
4      type3       3000         3000                 
5      type1       2000         3000                  
6      type2       -500            0                 
7      type3       5000         2000
8      type1      -1000         4000
```

and so on
that means each type must have its current total amount based on amount type
and its need to be dont have while loop because it takes long time to execute

```
for eg:

in type 1

ID      Amount      current 
1      2000-add       2000                   
2      1000-sub       1000                  
3      2000-add       3000                   
4      1000-add       4000
```

how to do it

Comment: Can you update your expected results table as well, now that you've changed your input spec?

Comment: now i corrected it @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, now question -> new post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query will work:

select id,type,amount,(select sum(amount) from mytable t1 where t1.type=t2.type and t1.id<=t2.id) currenttotal from mytable t2

Comment: your answer is ok but i want output like above @rahulRanjan

Comment: This is a correlated query, in order to improve performance you should avoid its:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Answer (score 0):

A self join is enough:

```
 select
    t1.id, t1.type, t1.amount, sum(t2.amount) as currenttotal
 from
  t t1 inner join t t2
 on t1.id >= t2.id and t1.type = t2.type
 group by
    t1.id, t1.type, t1.amount
 order by t1.id
```

**[Test it at sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fc70/10/0)**:

```
| ID |  TYPE | AMOUNT | CURRENTTOTAL |
--------------------------------------
|  1 | type1 |   2000 |         2000 |
|  2 | type1 |   1000 |         3000 |
|  3 | type2 |    500 |          500 |
|  4 | type3 |   3000 |         3000 |
|  5 | type1 |   2000 |         5000 |
|  6 | type2 |    500 |         1000 |
|  7 | type3 |   5000 |         8000 |
|  8 | type1 |  -1000 |         4000 |
```

**Explanation**

You can not use [windowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) functions because you don't aggregate for all rows of a same value but for previous rows of same value. Then, you need a non equi join to same table, you get in join all previous rows ( `t1.id >= t2.id` ) of same value (  `t1.type = t2.type` )

Comment: i have one more doubt and need to edit the question now @danihp

Comment: sorry for what i did but the above result which i mentioned in question is i want......@danihp