# Better Performance for calculating running total Operation in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, select

[Update table Data without using while loop in sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825830/update-table-data-without-using-while-loop-in-sql-server-2005)

i asked this question and Details are....

in sql i have table data like below

```
id      type     amount       
1      type1       2000    
2      type1       1000     
3      type2        500    
4      type3       3000    
5      type1       2000   
6      type2        500        
7      type3       5000    
8      type1       1000
```

and i want to get datas in select statement like below

```
id      type     amount      current   
1      type1       2000         2000                
2      type1       1000         1000                 
3      type2        500          500                 
4      type3       3000         3000                 
5      type1       2000         3000                  
6      type2       -500            0                 
7      type3       5000         2000
8      type1      -1000         4000
```

and so on
that means each type must have its current total amount based on amount type
and its need to be dont have while loop because it takes long time to execute

```
for eg:

in type 1

ID      Amount      current 
1      2000-add       2000                   
2      1000-sub       1000                  
3      2000-add       3000                   
4      1000-add       4000
```

and the answer is,

```
SELECT id,
       type,
       amount,
       (SELECT sum(amount)
        FROM   mytable t1
        WHERE  t1.type = t2.type
               AND t1.id <= t2.id) currenttotal
FROM   mytable t2
```

Now problem is assume the example table have 8000(it will Increase) records of Data like

```
id      type     amount       
1      type1       2000    
2      type1       1000     
3      type2        500    
4      type3       3000    
5      type1       2000   
6      type2        500        
7      type3       5000    
8      type1       1000
```

and its take `00:00:02` time for execute the select statement which i written based on the answer(have 2 answers and both have same execution time) for above question.How to reduce this time of execution?

Comment: *How to reduce this time of execution?* Do you have indexes to support the query? I assume you have at least looked at the execution plan.

Comment: Downvoted please add more detail.

Comment: The appropriate index for that query being on `type,id INCLUDE (amount)` though if you have a lot of rows per `type` performance will still be bad.

Comment: downvote for even added link for question....that will explain all @Namphibian

Comment: Questions should be self contained. I found it annoying too that I had to visit some other page first to even know what your question was.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX ON YourTable(type,id) INCLUDE (amount)
```

As long as the number of rows per `type` doesn't get too large the query in your question should be OK.

SQL Server 2012 has better support for calculating running totals than previous versions do. In SQL Server 2012  you could just do

```
SELECT id,
       type,
       amount,
      SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY type 
                         ORDER BY id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) currenttotal
FROM   mytable t2
```

Comment: please explain more and give example with above datas i given...please

Comment: @Suresh - My suggestion is to create an index on your table. There isn't really an example I can give you. The first line of code in my answer is the complete syntax to do this. Creating the index will hopefully mean your existing query will work in an acceptable time.

Comment: `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` means?

Comment: @Suresh - That query will not work in SQL Server 2005 I just provided it in case moving to SQL Server 2012 is an option. It essentially means Sum all the rows with a `type` from the first row (`UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`) to the current row.

Comment: i cant change my entire project for just one coding that you also understand what i am saying...any option in sql server 2005 please tell me....

Comment: Have you created the index yet?

Comment: i dont know about create index....but my table have one primary key filed that is `id`